Installing Grub on btrfs /boot when root is on ZFS
I'd like to use Grub for booting my Linux system. The system has its root filesystem on a ZFS dataset, it has the usual EFI boot partition, and a btrfs partition that can be used as /boot. When the system is booted up and I have both /boot and /boot/efi mounted, running update-grub prints the following error and then only installs the fallback "UEFI Firmware Settings" entry:
Found linux image: vmlinux-5.15.0-101-generic in rpool/UBUNTU
Found initrd image: initrd.img-5.15.0-101-generic in rpool/UBUNTU
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: unknown filesystem.

I understand that Grub doesn't have complete ZFS support, but that's exactly why I have this extra btrfs partition for /boot! I am baffled why the ZFS stuff even factors into booting here -- I thought Grub would load the initrd from /boot and then the rest of the process would be taken care of by Linux itself.
What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?
EDITED TO ADD: I've now noticed that update-grub does indeed generate a Grub entry for Linux, it just doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it, but it might be some very pertinent information for tracking it down.
The problem seems to be that the generated /boot/grub/grub.cfg file contains entries like this:
menuentry 'Ubuntu 22.04 LTS' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os ${menuentry_id_option} 'gnulinux-rpool/UBUNTU-5.15.0-101-generic' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode ${linux_gfx_mode}
        insmod gzio
        if [ "${grub_platform}" = xen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        linux   "/UBUNTU@/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-101-generic" root=ZFS="rpool/UBUNTU" ro quiet splash ${vt_handoff}
        initrd  "/UBUNTU@/boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-101-generic"
}

Note that the root parameter is correctly set to root=ZFS=rpool/UBUNTU, but linux and initrd incorrectly starts with /UBUNTU@/boot instead of (hd0,3).

You could find some settings related to your distro on the Root on ZFS section of the  openZFS doc.

UEFI ESP must be a FAT partition.

@Vilinkameni my UEFI ESP is mounted as /boot/efi and is a VFAT partition. My /boot is btrfs. This setup works if my root is not ZFS, so it's not the issue. I have tried using VFAT for /boot as well but that leads to problems when installing a kernel tries to create a vmlinuz symlink pointing to the latest kernel.

@freezed the Ubuntu section of that document describes a setup where ZFS is used for the /boot partition which is not what I'm trying to do.

To use any filesystem, kernel needs to have a driver for it, either compiled-in, or loaded as a module. Typically in the latter case initramfs is used. Logically, both kernel and initramfs must be on a partition that is readable to GRUB, before the kernel is loaded. To make a partition readable, appropriate GRUB module should be configured for GRUB. According to Arch wiki page on GRUB, GRUB has the btrfs module, used by insmod btrfs.

@Vilinkameni: I'm not sure what you're trying to say here. I do have btrfs drivers in my initramfs. Please see my latest edit -- it seems the problem is that wrong Grub entries are generated.

There are two separate "drivers"/modules, make sure you understand the difference: kernel modules and GRUB modules. Edit the GRUB entry to include the command I listed, as stated in an example on the quoted Arch wiki page.

@Vilinkameni since the generated grub.cfg file has the wrong linux and initrd config values (see my edit to the post), Grub never even gets to trying to read initrd from the btrfs /boot.

Again, the menuentry from the OP doesn't contain the line I mentioned, insmod btrfs. Insert that line (before the linux... and initrd... lines) as I suggested and try again. Again: to read the disk holding the initramfs (initrd.img*), GRUB needs to be able to read the filesystem it is on, for which it needs a GRUB module btrfs.

You can edit the entries yourself if they are incorrect as well (change /UBUNTU@/boot/... to (hd0,3)/boot/...). However, it is likely the btrfs subvolume is indeed UBUNTU@, so first try adding the insmod btrfs line, and if that doesn't work, then try changing the pathnames in the menuentry.

@Vilinkameni note that the correct initrd/kernel value would be (hd0,3)/initrd.img, not (hd0,3)/boot/initrd.img. So that already suggests that the problem is not just Grub not loading some btrfs driver. Adding insmod btrfs doesn't fix things. Also, manually fixing initrd / kernel to (hd0,3)/... does work, so this is not a problem with Grub not being able to read btrfs. Also also, my /boot file system has no subvolumes, so none named UBUNTU@.

@Vilinkameni in summary, if only update-grub generated the correct (hd0,3)/initrd.img etc. lines, this problem would be solved without any further btrfs-related tweaking.
